# Multi object tracking from centroids

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing, kalman-filter, object-tracking

I have a stationery video of me pedaling a bike, and my goal is to track the position of my joints and then compute some angles etc. The joints are marked with a color tape. Based on the color of the tape, i threshold the frames, detect contours and compute centroids of those contours. These are my detections. This approach was suggested to me here: [Methods to track marked points in a stationary video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340747/methods-to-track-marked-points-in-a-stationary-video) where i first asked about this topic. This works well, but I'm struggling with tracking those detections across the video.

I tried to compute distance of every tracked point to all the detections next frame, and then greedily assign point with lowest distance to the nearest detection. However, this does not work well if there are multiple points close together (the foot) because the near points are "switching" between frames (the ankle point becomes the toe point etc).

link to a video showcasing this: https://youtu.be/g0kED6EBg54

I tried to use [this](https://github.com/piercus/kalman-filter) implementation of kalman filter, to better predict the next location of the tracked point, but I don't really understand how it works so I am not sure how to set it to work better. This is the setting that I'm using:

```
                    // new kalman filter
                kalman_filters.push(new KalmanFilter({
                    observation: 2,
                    dynamic: {
                        name: 'constant-speed', // works better than constant-position and constant acceleration. idk why
                        timeStep: 5, // works better than default 1 idk why
                    }

                }));
```

How can i better track the points, so the points that are close wont switch with each other?

The whole codebase is on [github](https://github.com/vlasakjiri/opencv.js) (only index.html is relevant) and is deployed here: https://vlasakjiri.github.io/opencv.js/

How to use:
the top canvas shows current frame of the video. Small green circles are detected contours, filled colorful circles are matched points, hollow colorful circles are predictions from the kalman filter. The bottom canvas shows the result of the thresholding

1. Click on some points marked with the red tape. The thresholding will adjust and these points will now be tracked
2. Play the video

Comment: if your centroids have no identity or identifying information (for similarity/dissimilarity assessment), this is made harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have a thresholded image on which i find contours.  Could this be used to better identify the contours? The contours are pretty similar though: https://imgur.com/JeYSD43

Comment: this is merely about how points move too much from frame to frame... you use a Kalman filter (or anything simpler...) to ___predict___ where a point ___should___ be in the current frame, and you do the nearest neighbor assignment ___from there___, because that is the best prediction, with the least error

Comment: I suggest you to check whether the Klaman FIlter is overshooting or undershooting and tune it accordingly